# Hover effect does not work on small screen

Tags: html, css

When I resize the screen for mobile devices and I hover over links in menu, nothing happens. I don't understand what is wrong. Funny thing is, when I click on the link, the color changes to what it should be when I hover. I tried hover over li and a and both are non functional. Did I miss something?

```
<nav id="myNav">
            <div class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
            </div>
            <div class="top-nav">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

---

```
  nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
     
nav ul {
  max-height: 0px;
  background: #000;
}

.show-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: azure;
}

nav ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Are u using a bootstraps? or Any other CSS?

Comment: No, I use plain CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when it hits the `media size` your max `list height` is `0px`. So it will not render Visibly

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {

nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Remove the `max-height: 0px;`

```js
function myFunction() {
}
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}
.menu {
   background-color: lightgray;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
     
nav ul {
  background: #000;
}

.show-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 </head>
<nav id="myNav">
    <div class="menu-icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
    </div>
    <div class="top-nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: But if I do that, the menu will be visible the whole time and I don't want that. I want it to be visible only when I click on the icon.

Comment: control the visibility using js, once the hamburger menu button is clicked you toggle the visibility.

Comment: Yea, I did that. I click the hamburger, menu shows up, but hover effect is not working. :/

Comment: I tweaked with the hover colors a bit. Specially the `background-color: rgba(240, 255, 255, 0.3);` See if that works

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: It works now somehow. You know what the funny thing is? I did not change anything. I am confused. Maybe it has something to do with me resizing manually instead of clicking toggle device tool bar in developer tools. Thanks anyway, man!

Answer (score 0):

Is it because on phone we don't have hover effect (we use touch pad)?